# Divisores por iteradores

Tags: python

necesito diseñar un módulo el cual devuelva uno por uno y en orden ascendente, todos los divisores de un número entero positivo.

```
class Divisores:

    def __init__(self, number):

        if type(number) == int and number > 0:
            self.__number = number
        else:
            raise ValueError("Se ha producido una excepción")

    def __iter__(self):
        number = self.__number
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        for elements in range(1, number + 1):
            if number % elements == 0:
                return elements

    for i in Divisores(12):
        print(i)
```

**Examples**
for v in Divisores(5):
   print(v)

**Salida esperada**
1
5

for t in Divisores(12):
   print(t)

**Salida esperada:**
1
2
3
4
6
12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que el rango del `for` siempre se inicia en 1, por lo que `__iter__` retorna 1 infinitamente.

Para usar un enfoque de fuerza bruta con un `for` necesitas almacenar el último divisor encontrado y iniciar el ciclo con `ultimo_divisor + 1`:

```
class Divisores:

    def __init__(self, number):
        if isinstance(number, int) and number > 0:
            self._number = number
        else:
            raise ValueError("number debe ser un entero positivo")

    def __iter__(self):
        self._divisor = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        for n in range(self._divisor + 1, self._number + 1):
            if self._number % n == 0:
                self._divisor = n
                return self._divisor
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

La cláusula `else` en la estructura `for - else` solo se ejecuta si el `for` se ha completado, que en este caso es si se ha llegado a `self._number`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación, pero me ha surgido una duda tratando el tema de los iteradores. Dicha cuestión es la siguiente: Podemos considerar que en el método __iter__ se almacenan, por lo general, estructuras genéricas, tales como contadores, que posteriormente emplearemos en el método __next__, almacenando por tanto, en este último método estructuras más "complejas" de tratamiento y condiciones. Gracias

Comment: Hola María, creo que tu duda sobre la función de ambos métodos podría ser una buena pregunta tal como la planteas. Si no tienes mucho inconveniente considera crear una nueva pregunta, dónde es más fácil dar una respuesta más completa. Un saludo.

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias